# on click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one  in which I will be having multiple child components, at first if I click at any component, the corresponding click event should be triggered and after that no other component click event within that div should not trigger unless otherwise the mouse moves out of the  borderline and again comes back in.

I have done the following stuff to achieve this, right now the first part is complete that is when we click at any component the corresponding click event will be triggered and after that no other component click event within that div will occur since I am removing the click event using `.off("click");`

but now the issue is that when the mouse leaves the div, I want to reattach the click event which is not happening when i used the following code,

```
$('.parent *').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(".parent *").on('click')
});
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvm1ajjL/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function clickEvents(){
        $("#myButton").off().on('click',function () {
            console.log('myButton clicked....');
        });

        $("#myHyperLink").off().on('click',function () {
            console.log('myHyperLink clicked....');
        });
    }

    $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function () {
       clickEvents()
    });

    $(".parent").click(function (event) {
        $(".parent *").off("click");
    });
 clickEvents()
```

});

You also can try this.

Comment: can you explain what it is happening

Comment: create function which having an events which is getting called onready event first and after that when you click on any button event bubbles till parent and parent click getting called in which all the clicks of child have to off,
and on mouseleave simply reattach the events by calling same function.
.off().on() uses for if event is attached before remove it and attach new one, its better to use full syntax of .offf() method

Comment: I am getting confused,,,,,,,,,,not getting u

Comment: ok cool, let's go line by line:
1. we created simple function in which we attached the events for both link and button and this function getting envoked at ready first
2. and also we attached click event to parent for removing click events of childs which is getting called on click of any child of parent and childs events getting detached.
3. on mouse leave we want to attach the events again so we just called the function which having events.

Comment: that would be fine, I guess

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide event handler for `click` event:

```
$(".parent *").on('click', function () {
    console.log('Event occured');
    // Your event handler function call here
});
```

Comment: actually I want the childs event to occur after mouse leave

Comment: $(".parent *").mouseleave(function() {

  console.log('Event occured');

});

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add a removed handler by calling `on('click')`, you need to pass the event handlers.

One possible solution is to know whether the parent is already clicked, then don't do anything, for which you can use a class like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        if (isParentClicked(this)) {
            return;
        }
        console.log('myButton clicked....');
    });

    $("#myHyperLink").click(function () {
        if (isParentClicked(this)) {
            return;
        }
        console.log('myHyperLink clicked....');
    });

    function isParentClicked(el) {
        return $(el).closest('.parent').hasClass('clicked');
    }

    $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked')
    });

    $(".parent").click(function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('clicked')
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4gzaghaj/)

---

Another possible solution is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).closest('.parent').hasClass('clicked')) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  })

  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    console.log('myButton clicked....');
  });

  $("#myHyperLink").click(function() {
    console.log('myHyperLink clicked....');
  });

  $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked')
  });

  $(".parent").click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent' style="width:100px;border:2px solid blue">
  <button id="myButton" class="clickable">Click Me</button>
  <a href="#" id="myHyperLink" class="clickable">Click Me Too</a>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4gzaghaj/2/)

Comment: syms solutions seems to be simplest one I guess, what you say

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the click event to a particular function so that on click it can fire that function.

```
$('.parent *').on('mouseleave', function () {
  $(".parent *").off('click').on("click",functionName);
});
```

That's all to bind the click again.
hope this may help you.
Thanks!!

Comment: wat this `.off('click').on("click"` means

Comment: off click used here to unbind any previous attached click events and on click for binding new one